# How to replace all $character that match

Tags: php, regex

I have a question how to change $to a code

Here's my code

```
<?php
    $str = 'Hello $jack$ crus $here$!';

    function phc($str){
       preg_match('/\$(.*?)\$/', $str, $match);
        $output = str_replace($match[0],"<span style = 'color: teal' class = 'colorhere'>".$match[1]."</span>",$str);

        return $output;
    }

    echo phc($str);
?>
```

That code works but only the word jack change the color my question is how to change all $ (dollar sign)

Answer (score 3):

I seem to need to escape the literal dollar signs *twice* to get it work.  Also, I would just use a single call to `preg_replace` here, which by default already does a global replacement.

```
$str = 'Hello $jack$ crus $here$!';
$output = preg_replace("/\\$(.*?)\\$/", "<span style = 'color: teal' class = 'colorhere'>$1</span>", $str);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
Hello <span style = 'color: teal' class = 'colorhere'>jack</span> crus <span style = 'color: teal' class = 'colorhere'>here</span>!
```

Comment: The one backslash escapes for the double quotes, and the second for the PCRE processor so it is not the end of line character. You could do `preg_replace('/[$](.*?)[$]/'` and no escaping is needed.